# Can I run a SELECT query that depends on two rows from a table without using subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose the schemas are

```
users(id, name)
users_attributes(user_id, attribute_name, attribute_value)
```

Sample data:

```
--
-- Database: `sample_db`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `sample_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
USE `sample_db`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Tim'),
(2, 'Joe'),
(3, 'Bob');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users_attributes`
--

CREATE TABLE `users_attributes` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attribute_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `attribute_value` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users_attributes`
--

INSERT INTO `users_attributes` (`user_id`, `attribute_name`, `attribute_value`) VALUES
(1, 'height', '10'),
(1, 'over_18', 'yes'),
(2, 'height', '5'),
(3, 'height', '7');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `users_attributes`
--
ALTER TABLE `users_attributes`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`attribute_name`,`attribute_value`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
COMMIT;
```

Right now I'm calling INNER JOIN on a specific attribute_name so my selection also returns that along with the user id and name. Now I want to exclude from whatever I selected, if they contain a certain other attribute. I know I can accomplish that by using a NOT IN (SELECT ...) conditional but can I do that without having to select again?

EDIT:
Attributes may or may not exist for all users. For example, I would like to fetch id, name, attribute_value where attribute_name = height but only if attribute_name over_18 does not exist or is 'no'

Comment: Please show the two tables with sample data and the expected outcome.

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each table, and paste it into the questions as text (NOT A PICTURE). 
An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful, and a view of your expected output based on the table data you show as an example.
If at all possible create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the schema defined and some test data provided.

Comment: You must join 2 copies of attribute table. First - INNER JOIN with needed attribute, another - LEFT JOIN with unwanted attribute(s) without matched row.

Comment: I've updated the question with sample data